# AutoComplete using a Trie in Java

Tags: java, autocomplete, trie, breadth-first-search

I am working on this assignment which implements Autocomplete and dictionary. I have sucessfully implemented spellcheck and the addWord() and isWord() functions.
But I am just not able to implement the function which predicts words for AutoCompletions.

```
package spelling;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;

/** 
 * An trie data structure that implements the Dictionary and the AutoComplete ADT
 * @author You
 *
 */
public class AutoCompleteDictionaryTrie implements  Dictionary, AutoComplete {
private TrieNode root;
private int size;


public AutoCompleteDictionaryTrie()
{
    root = new TrieNode();
    size=0;
}


/** Insert a word into the trie.
 * For the basic part of the assignment (part 2), you should ignore the word's case.
 * That is, you should convert the string to all lower case as you insert it. */
public boolean addWord(String word)
{
    //TODO: Implement this method.
    String Word=word.toLowerCase();
    if(isWord(Word))
        return false;
    HashMap<Character, TrieNode> children=root.children;
    for(int i=0; i<Word.length(); i++){
        char c = Word.charAt(i);
        TrieNode t;
        if(children.containsKey(c)){
                t = children.get(c);
        }else{
            t = new TrieNode(""+(c));
            children.put(c, t);
        }

        children = t.children;
        if(i==Word.length()-1)
        {
            t.isWord = true; 
            size++;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/** 
 * Return the number of words in the dictionary.  This is NOT necessarily the same
 * as the number of TrieNodes in the trie.
 */
public int size()
{
    //TODO: Implement this method
    return size;
}


/** Returns whether the string is a word in the trie */
@Override
public boolean isWord(String s) 
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    TrieNode t = searchNode(s.toLowerCase());

    if(t != null && t.isWord) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public TrieNode searchNode(String str){
    HashMap<Character, TrieNode> children = root.children; 
    TrieNode t = null;
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if(children.containsKey(c)){
            t = children.get(c);
            children = t.children;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    return t;
}

/** 
 *  * Returns up to the n "best" predictions, including the word itself,
 * in terms of length
 * If this string is not in the trie, it returns null.
 * @param text The text to use at the word stem
 * @param n The maximum number of predictions desired.
 * @return A list containing the up to n best predictions
 */@Override
 public List<String> predictCompletions(String prefix, int numCompletions) 
 {
     // TODO: Implement this method
     // This method should implement the following algorithm:
     // 1. Find the stem in the trie.  If the stem does not appear in the trie, return an
     //    empty list
     // 2. Once the stem is found, perform a breadth first search to generate completions
     //    using the following algorithm:
     //    Create a queue (LinkedList) and add the node that completes the stem to the back
     //       of the list.
     //    Create a list of completions to return (initially empty)
     //    While the queue is not empty and you don't have enough completions:
     //       remove the first Node from the queue
     //       If it is a word, add it to the completions list
     //       Add all of its child nodes to the back of the queue
     // Return the list of completions
     List<String> completions=null;
     int counter=0;
     if (prefix==null){
         return Collections.emptyList();
     }

     prefix=prefix.toLowerCase();
     if(isWord(prefix))
         completions.add(prefix);
     LinkedList nodes = new LinkedList();

     TrieNode curr=searchNode(prefix);
     nodes.addLast(curr);
     while(!nodes.isEmpty() && counter!=numCompletions)
     {
         if((nodes.removeFirst()).isWord)
         completions.add(curr.getText());
         TrieNode next = null;
         for (Character c : curr.getValidNextCharacters()) {
                next = curr.getChild(c);
         }
     }


     return Collections.emptyList();

 }
 public void checkNull(String word){
    if (word==null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Null word passed");
 }
// For debugging
public void printTree()
{
    printNode(root);
}

/** Do a pre-order traversal from this node down */
public void printNode(TrieNode curr)
{
    if (curr == null) 
        return;

    System.out.println(curr.getText());

    TrieNode next = null;
    for (Character c : curr.getValidNextCharacters()) {
        next = curr.getChild(c);
        printNode(next);
    }
}



}
```

And this is the code of the TrieNode class:

```
package spelling;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

/** 
* Represents a node in a Trie
* @author UC San Diego Intermediate Programming MOOC Team
*
 */
class TrieNode {
HashMap<Character, TrieNode> children; 
private String text;  // Maybe omit for space
boolean isWord;

/** Create a new TrieNode */
public TrieNode()
{
    children = new HashMap<Character, TrieNode>();
    text = "";
    isWord = false;
}

/** Create a new TrieNode given a text String to store in it */
public TrieNode(String text)
{
    this();
    this.text = text;
}

/** Return the TrieNode that is the child when you follow the 
 * link from the given Character 
 * @param c The next character in the key
 * @return The TrieNode that character links to, or null if that link
 *   is not in the trie.
 */
public TrieNode getChild(Character c)
{
    return children.get(c);
}

/** Inserts this character at this node.
 * Returns the newly created node, if c wasn't already
 * in the trie.  If it was, it does not modify the trie
 * and returns null.
 * @param c The character that will link to the new node
 * @return The newly created TrieNode, or null if the node is already 
 *     in the trie.
 */
public TrieNode insert(Character c)
{
    if (children.containsKey(c)) {
        return null;
    }

    TrieNode next = new TrieNode(text + c.toString());
    children.put(c, next);
    return next;
}

/** Return the text string at this node */
public String getText()
{
    return text;
}

/** Set whether or not this node ends a word in the trie. */
public void setEndsWord(boolean b)
{
    isWord = b;
}

/** Return whether or not this node ends a word in the trie. */
public boolean endsWord()
{
    return isWord;
}

/** Return the set of characters that have links from this node */
public Set<Character> getValidNextCharacters()
{
    return children.keySet();
}

}
```

Even though the algorithm is there I am not able to implement it. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you trying to solve this as part of the Coursera's university of San Diego course?
If so then all what you have to do is to follow the algorithm that was written as a comment inside the class.
Any way, I added here a copy of my implementation to this method. Just don't copy and paste it as part of your solution please. Use it as guidance. I added comments in the code to help you understanding my algorithm:

```
     //Trying to find the stem in Trie
     String prefixToCheckLowerCase = prefix.toLowerCase();
     int completionsCount = 0;
     List<String> completions = new LinkedList<String>();
     TrieNode traversal = root;
     for (int i = 0; i < prefixToCheckLowerCase.length(); i++)
     {
         if (traversal.getValidNextCharacters().contains(prefixToCheckLowerCase.charAt(i)))
        {
            traversal = traversal.getChild(prefixToCheckLowerCase.charAt(i));
        } 
         //Means  stem not found, returns an empty list
         else
            return completions;
     }
     //If current word is an end word, increment the counter and add it to compeltions list
     if (traversal.endsWord()) 
     {
         completionsCount=1;
         completions.add(traversal.getText());
     }

     List<TrieNode> nodesToBeSearched = new LinkedList<TrieNode>();
     List<Character> ChildCharaterList = new LinkedList<Character>(traversal.getValidNextCharacters());
     //Filling the list with children of the current node, first level of of the breadth first search 
     for (int i=0; i<ChildCharaterList.size(); i++) 
     {
         nodesToBeSearched.add(traversal.getChild(ChildCharaterList.get(i)));
     }
     //while loop for the linked list elements and see if any compeltions exists , inside it we will also check each node children and add them to the list!!!
     while (nodesToBeSearched!=null  && nodesToBeSearched.size()>0 && completionsCount < numCompletions)
     {
         TrieNode trieNode = nodesToBeSearched.remove(0);
         if (trieNode.endsWord()) 
         {
             completionsCount++;
             completions.add(trieNode.getText());
         }

         List<Character> subTrieNodeCholdren = new LinkedList<Character>(trieNode.getValidNextCharacters());
         //Adding all next level tries to the linked list , kinda recursive!!!
         for (int i=0; i<subTrieNodeCholdren.size();i++) 
         {
             nodesToBeSearched.add(trieNode.getChild(subTrieNodeCholdren.get(i)));
         }
     }
     return completions;
```

Comment: Yes Mohamed it's for the UCSD course. Since the time I posted this, I went on to implement this function using the already existing PrintNode() function. So I won't be misusing your code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
class TrieNode{
    char data;
    boolean isTerminating;
    TrieNode children[];
    int childCount;

    public TrieNode(char data) {
        this.data = data;
        isTerminating = false;
        children = new TrieNode[26];
        childCount = 0;
    }
}

public class Trie {
    private TrieNode root;
    //ArrayList<String> ans=new ArrayList<>();

    public Trie() {
        root = new TrieNode('\0');
    }

    private void add(TrieNode root, String word){
        if(word.length() == 0){
            root.isTerminating = true;
            return;
        }       
        int childIndex = word.charAt(0) - 'a';
        TrieNode child = root.children[childIndex];
        if(child == null){
            child = new TrieNode(word.charAt(0));
            root.children[childIndex] = child;
            root.childCount++;
        }
        add(child, word.substring(1));
    }

    public void add(String word){
        add(root, word);
    }

    private void searchHelper(TrieNode root,String word,String ans)
    {
      try
      {
      if(word.length()==0)
      {
        if(root.isTerminating == true)
        {
          System.out.println(ans);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
        {
          TrieNode temp=root.children[i];
          if(temp !=null)
          {
            //ans=ans+temp.data;
            //System.out.println("test check "+ans );
            searchHelper(temp,word,ans+temp.data);
          }
        }
      }
      int childIndex=word.charAt(0)-'a';
      TrieNode child=root.children[childIndex];
      if(child == null)
      {
        //System.out.print();
        return ;
      }
      ans=ans+word.charAt(0);
      searchHelper(child,word.substring(1),ans);

    }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
        //System.out.println("error");
      }
    }

    public void  search(String word)
    {
      String s="";
      searchHelper(root,word,s);
    }

    public void autoComplete(ArrayList<String> input, String word) {
        // Complete this function
        // Print the output as specified in question
        Trie ansTrie = new Trie();
        for(int i=0;i<input.size();i++)
        {
            ansTrie.add(input.get(i)); 
        }
        ansTrie.search(word);
    }
}
```

i hope it helps in solving you doubt.
i am already sorry for any indentation errors .

Answer (score 0):

```
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.HashSet;
        import java.util.LinkedList;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Map;
        import java.util.Queue;
        import java.util.Set;
        import java.util.stream.Collectors;
        
            public class TrieImpl {
        
            static class Element {
                private Trie trie;
                private String word;
        
                Element(Trie trie, String word) {
                    this.trie = trie;
                    this.word = word;
                }
            }
        
            static class Trie {
                private boolean isLeaf;
                private Map<Character, Trie> children;
                private Map<Character, Integer> character;
        
                Trie() {
                    isLeaf = false;
                    children = new HashMap<>();
                    character = new HashMap<>();
                }
        
                public void insert(String word) {
                    Trie curr = this;
                    for (Character ch : word.toCharArray()) {
                        curr.children.putIfAbsent(ch, new Trie());
                        int count = (curr.character.get(ch) == null) ? 1 : curr.character.get(ch) + 1;
                        curr.character.put(ch, count);
                        curr = curr.children.get(ch);
                    }
                    curr.isLeaf = true;
                }
        
                public boolean search(String word) {
                    Trie curr = this;
                    for (Character ch : word.toCharArray()) {
                        if (curr.children.get(ch) == null)
                            return false;
                        curr = curr.children.get(ch);
                    }
                    return curr.isLeaf;
                }
        
                public void delete(String word) {
                    if (search(word)) {
                        Trie lastSecond = this;
                        Character charToRemove = word.charAt(0);
                        Trie curr = this;
                        int i = -1;
                        while (i < word.length() && curr != null) {
                            if (curr.isLeaf && i != word.length() - 1) {
                                charToRemove = word.charAt(i + 1);
                                lastSecond = curr;
                            }
                            i = i + 1;
                            if (i < word.length())
                                curr = curr.children.get(word.charAt(i));
                        }
                        lastSecond.children.remove(charToRemove);
                    }
                }
        
                public int findPrefixCount(String word) {
                    Trie curr = this;
                    Character lastChar = null;
                    int count = 0;
                    for (Character ch : word.toCharArray()) {
                        if (curr.children.get(ch) == null)
                            return 0;
                        if (count < word.length() - 1) {
                            curr = curr.children.get(ch);
                            count++;
                        }
                        lastChar = ch;
                    }
                    if (lastChar != null && curr.character.get(lastChar) != null)
                        return curr.character.get(lastChar);
                    else
                        return 0;
                }
        
                public Set<String> autoComplete(String word) {
                    Trie curr = this;
                    int count = 0;
                    String wo = "";
                    Queue<Element> queue = new LinkedList<>();
                    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
                    for (Character ch : word.toCharArray()) {
                        if (count < word.length()) {
                            curr = curr.children.get(ch);
                            count++;
                            wo += ch;
                        }
                    }
                    if (curr != null)
                        queue.add(new Element(curr, wo));
        
                    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                        Element elem = queue.poll();
                        Trie current = elem.trie;
                        String temp = elem.word;
                        if (current != null && current.isLeaf)
                            set.add(temp);
                        List<Character> keys = current.character.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
                        for (int i = 0; i < current.children.size(); i++) {
                            queue.add(new Element(current.children.get(keys.get(i)), temp + keys.get(i)));
                        }
        
                    }
                    return set;
        
                }
                    }
        
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                Trie head = new Trie();
                head.insert("techie");
                head.insert("techi");
                head.insert("tech");
                head.insert("tecabc");
                head.insert("tecabk");
                head.insert("tecabd");
                head.insert("tecalmz");
                Set<String> words = head.autoComplete("t");
                words.stream().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
        
            }
        
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).